# Why won't strcpy copy my string into another string?

Tags: c

I'm coding in C. Here's my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void function1(char sentence[])
{   
    char sentenceCopy[strlen(sentence)+1];

    strcpy(sentenceCopy, sentence);
    strcat(sentenceCopy, " ");

    printf("%s\n", sentence); // Prints the appropriate sentence passed to it
    printf("%s\n", sentenceCopy); // Prints "" (nothing), despite being copied
}

void function2(char sentence[], char param2[])
{
    function1(sentence); 
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    function2("'this should've been eight chars', said the computer", "should've");
}
```

Why isn't strcpy copying sentenceCopy into sentence? I can't seem to figure this out. Thank you.

EDIT: Thanks for the answers. However, it still won't work, despite me changing +1 to +2 for the length of sentenceCopy. Any ideas? I haven't a clue.

Comment: `sentenceCopy` is 1 char too short: you need space for all of the chars in `sentence`, plus the added space, PLUS the null terminator.

Comment: `function2` does not use the second argument. `function1` allocates just enough memory to copy the string passed, and then breaks it. Undefined behaviour. The `+1` is for the string terminator, not the concatenated space.

Comment: Note that `sentenceCopy` is a VLA (Variable Length Array). This feature was not supported in C90, was added in C99, and was made optional in C11. I'm not saying that's a problem, but you should be aware of the possible portability issue.

Answer (score 4):

The buffer you declare here:

```
char sentenceCopy[strlen(sentence)+1];
```

is *only* large enough for the contents of `sentence`. Appending another character to it using `strcat` overflows the buffer, causing undefined behavior.

Incidentally, this error can actually be picked up by a smart compiler:

```
# clang --analyze test.c
test.c:11:5: warning: String copy function overflows destination buffer
    strcat(sentenceCopy, " ");
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, upon adding 2 to the length of lineCopy (as opposed to 1), it still will not copy line into lineCopy. Do you have any idea why?